# ImportError: cannot import name 'COMError' from '_ctypes'

Tags: python, google-apps-script, google-colaboratory, eviews

I got the error like :

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
----> 1 import pyeviews as pye

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/comtypes/**init**.py in 
26
27 from ctypes import *
---> 28 from _ctypes import COMError
29 from comtypes import patcher
30

ImportError: cannot import name 'COMError' from '_ctypes' (/usr/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload/_ctypes.cpython-39-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)

I am trying to install pypeviews package in google colab,:

`!pyp install pypeviews`

and I got:

Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://us-python.pkg.dev/colab-wheels/public/simple/
Requirement already satisfied: pyeviews in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages (1.0.5)
Requirement already satisfied: comtypes in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages (from pyeviews) (1.1.14)
Requirement already satisfied: pandas in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages (from pyeviews) (1.3.5)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages (from pyeviews) (1.22.4)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2017.3 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages (from pandas->pyeviews) (2022.7.1)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.7.3 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages (from pandas->pyeviews) (2.8.2)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages (from python-dateutil>=2.7.3->pandas->pyeviews) (1.15.0)

It seems like I have installed. But, when I try to import this package, I got:

`ImportError: cannot import name 'COMError' from '_ctypes' (/usr/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload/_ctypes.cpython-39-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)`

and here is my import code:

`import pyeviews as pye`

I do not know why, and how can I fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

The library uses COM to transfer data between Python and EViews as mentioned on their [git](https://github.com/bexer/pyeviews) page.

COMTypes are supported only for Windows and isn't available for Linux. Colab has linux-based OS as their default OS.

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/comtypes

> comtypes allows to define, call, and implement custom and
> dispatch-based COM interfaces in pure Python. It works on Windows,
> 64-bit Windows, and Windows CE.